# Garbage characters in output file of swi-prolog protocol

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

When I use `protocol('execution.txt').`  and input some queries, I got some garbage characters in the output file. Is there any way to avoid these characters?

```
11 ?- beside(block2, X).
X = block3  [1m;[0m
[1;31mfalse.[0m

12 ?- beside(block4, X).
X = block7  [1m;[0m
X = block3  [1m;[0m
[1;31mfalse.[0m

13 ?- beside(block5, X).
[1;31mfalse.[0m

14 ?- above(block1,X).
X = block2  [1m;[0m
[1;31mfalse.[0m

15 ?- above(block2,X).
[1;31mfalse.[0m

16 ?- above(block6,X).
X = block5  [1m;[0m
X = block4  [1m;[0m
[1;31mfalse.[0m

17 ?- noprotocol.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

those characters are ANSI terminal control sequences, used to highlight errors, etc etc. To disable it, input

```
?- set_prolog_flag(color_term, false).
```

before starting the protocol session. To disable permanently, place the same as a directive in your preference file. I.e. in Unix, place in ~/.plrc

```
:- set_prolog_flag(color_term, false).
```

If you use XPCE EMACS, you can edit preferences from menu

```
Edit\Prolog preferences
```